# Do other sites have the right to copy and publish a post that has been deleted - especially when the OP requests they remove the content?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

CCwiki allows other sites to publish content from stack exchange given proper attribution. However, it is unclear to me if they can publish something from stackoverflow and attribute it to stack overflow if it was deleted from stack overflow. When a post is deleted from stack overflow does the publisher of the other website have an obligation to delete the copied content if they are notified of the SE deletion? What if the SO post is libelous or otherwise offensive and the attribution makes SO look bad? What happens if the original user contacts the other website and specifically asks for it to be removed or unattributed to his account?

this is effectively the same question as [How does the Creative Commons license affect deleted content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201609/how-does-the-creative-commons-license-affect-deleted-content). However, that question does not address the scenerio of "what happens if the user contacts the other website asking for them to remove the content?" aspect.

Comment: I've asked a similar question before: [How does the Creative Commons license affect deleted content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201609/how-does-the-creative-commons-license-affect-deleted-content)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you license material under CC:Wiki, you give other people irrevocable permission to reuse it, if they provide attribution.  When you post material to StackExchange, you license it under CC:Wiki.

The Creative Common License doesn't specifically mention deleted material, but since you can't revoke permission to reuse the content once you've CC:Wiki licensed it and published it, deleting the original will have no effect on that permission, *even if you remove the means to attribute you, the original author.*

Even if the post makes SE look bad, there's nothing they can do about copies of the material that they cannot control.  If the original author contacts the other website, the only obligation that the other website has is to disassociate the author from the material (i.e remove the attribution).

Comment: Weirdly, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/ is linked from every page and quotes some text defining "attribution" that I can't find in the CC license. The license says, "The credit required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable manner", not "You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor". So it's possible that your actual obligations are different from what SE thinks your obligations are.

Comment: ... I don't know the legal situation if you do something permitted by the license but forbidden by SE's ToS which is more specific and hence more restrictive than the license. For example: omitting the hyperlink because it no longer refers to anything or in a medium that does not have hyperlinks. Possibly you're entitled to do so per copyright law, but you lose the permission to access SE sites in future because you violated site ToS. IANAL.

Comment: @SteveJessop "You must attribute the work in the manner specified by the author or licensor" was part of the human-readable version of CC (as can still be seen [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License), for instance), and as far as I can tell, the blog post you link to was intended to clear up what that part of the CC license meant, and not to add any restrictions. If I'm correct, you shouldn't worry about that at all: either your use of the content will be both legal and accepted by SE, or it will be illegal.

Comment: @hvd: so what's the relationship between that summary and CC's own summary at https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/? Is Wiktionary's an old version of CC's and CC has since clarified what the license means? It seems like "in the manner specified" has been slightly over-interpreted by SE since the blog post says "do exactly this" and doesn't say "or anything else along these lines that gives the same credit".

Comment: Not that it will make a huge difference to most people anyway since they'll be happy to do what SE asks regardless of whether the license strictly-speaking requires it. But linking to a deleted question is a fairly unnatural act and SE claims to require it anyway :-) For another example I don't see how the "not nofollow" restriction is supported by the license. I suppose someone might fear that too many "follow" links to dead content will harm their own site's rank, but nevertheless want to distribute material from deleted questions for whatever reason.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, it's an old version of CC's, here's an [Internet Archive Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20090625084912/http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/) to one of the versions in the month of the blog post.